# How to capture GTP-C Traffic using mininet?

Tags: network-core, sdn

I am trying to capture the GTP-C packet, I am using Scapy  to generate GTP-C Packet.

But I could not find any good tutorial related to "How to use Scapy?"

Comment: Unfortunately, product or resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic here, as are applications. All you need to do is search the Internet - I found several sites in a matter of seconds.

Comment: As I explained, that is explicitly off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to Generate GTP packet?

Answer:

STEP1: 
Download gtp.py (https://github.com/cisco-system-traffic-generator/trex-core/blob/master/scripts/external_libs/scapy-2.3.1/python3/scapy/contrib/gtp.py)

run this program on linux terminal with command:

sudo python gtp.py

Above and below both commands both are same just telling how to give path for program.

sudo python "(path to the program)"

STEP2.

data = ('32 ff 00 58 00 00 00 01 28 db 00 00 45 00 00 54 00 00 40 00 40 00 5e a5 ca 0b 28 9e c0 a8 28 b2 08 00 be e7 00 00 28 7b 04 11 20 4b f4 3d 0d 00 08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 1a 1b 1c 1d 1e 1f 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 2a 2b 2c 2d 2e 2f 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37')

data_list = data.split(" ")

data_s = ''.join(data_list).decode('hex')

sendp(Ether()/IP(dst="1.1.1.1", proto=17, len=124)/UDP(sport=2152,dport=2152,len=104)/GTPHeader(teid=2807)/GTPCreatePDPContextRequest()/Raw(load=data_s))